# Javascript/Angular : In Network tab how can I hide login API call after successfully login in my application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, api, security

How can I hide login API call from Network tab after successfully login ?
**My concern is that this API call is clearly visible in network panel of Chrome development tools.That what I don't
want in my network panel.**

Comment: What if we add flag to UI for encryption in HTTP headers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the network tab from your application. This means that you can't hide any call to your API or resource call. Everything you put into frontend (code, calls, keys, etc) should be considered as public and insecure.

Comment: What if we add flag to UI for encryption in HTTP headers.

Comment: Yes, you can encrypt something in UI using the public key and asymmetric cipher. But even in this case, at some moment, the value will be non-encyrpted and can be read by the client. The main issue is, that if I want, I can intercept the response even before your code or browser will take care about it. Could you explain what exact issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You don't control the user agent (browser). The user agent belongs to the user. It may show him anything he wants. It may allow him to debug through the JS code line by line. It may and will show him all requests that are performed. If the Chrome allows to hide the network tab due to some programmatic trickery, the user will be able to build his own user agent that does not prevent that.